# Multiple sourceDirectory entries in jasperreports maven plugin

Tags: maven, compilation, jasper-reports, maven-plugin

I have several locations of my jasper reports within the project, not simply one `sourceDirectory` like the default `src/main/jasperreports`.

Are multiple source directories/subdirectories supported for this plugin?

Comment: How should i know. Have you taken a look into the documentation of te plugin?

Comment: Yes, I've looked through the documentation. I did not notice anything that applied to this issue, I'm wondering if anyone else has or knows of anything possibly undocumented.
Or perhaps what I'm looking for is covered under a different plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Try this structure:

```
-src
--- main
------java
--------jasperreports
-----------dir1
-----------dir2

<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/jasperreports</sourceDirectory>
```

The jasper maven plugin will compile all reports under jasperreports folder and subfolders.